# What is Titanium.Geolocation.lastGeolocation in Titanium?

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-alloy

In Titanium there is the following property:

```
Titanium.Geolocation.lastGeolocation
```

As explained in this doc: http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Geolocation

It is described as follows:

> JSON representation of the last geolocation received.
>
> LastEvent is the JSON version of the last geolocation sent by the OS.
>   This does not trigger a geolocation attempt, nor wait for such. If no
>   geolocation has happened, this value may be null or undefined.

My question is when it says "lastGeolocation", does it mean the last geolocation recieved my the device ever (e.g. The app could have got a location from another app such as Google Maps), or just the last geolocation received by the app?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it should be the device's last location irrespective to which app requested for it.

It is easily checkable with following steps:

1. Get a fresh current location from the Titanium app & check the value of lastLocation.
2. Do a location request from another place with different app like Google Maps.
3. Then check it again in Titanium app.

Comment: That is correct. On Android it is reading the systems last location; from TiLocation.java it is accessing:  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#getLastKnownLocation(java.lang.String)